# Moved Target to New Project in Xcode, GLEW won't compile anymore

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, glew

I have just moved a target from one project to another (or more correctly created a new target in the other project and moved the source across) and now get an error:

```
#error gl.h included before glew.h
```

I have also changed compilers (from GCC 4.0 to LLVM 3.0) and moved from Xcode 3.2.6 to 4.2.
 Converting the existing project (the "old" project) when changing Xcode version and compiler doesn't have the same problem. The base SDK for the old project was OSX 10.5, but for both was converted to 10.6.

So far I have matched up the build settings for the appropriate target, and also the build phase settings. I have also converted GLEW to a static library and added that correctly. If I compile on a 10.7 machine using the base SDK Mac OS X Latest (10.7) the problem seems to disappear.

Is there something hideously obvious that I have missed?? Surely there is. A mysterious Xcode setting somewhere perhaps??

The problem doesn't seem to be there when a base SDK of

Answer (score 1):

I had this error in a project last week. Basically you can't include gl.h, glu.h or glut.h BEFORE glew.h. Check your includes and I'm pretty sure you are either including one of these files before GLEW or including a file that include gl.h (etc) again before you include glew.h.

More info: http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I definitely have been going around checking that, as that is the error. And yes, it is spaghetti code, so it's possible. The reason I think that probably isn't the reason, is that the original target in the old/existing project does not have the same problem and using the 10.7 Base SDK seems to resolve the issue (although unfortunately this isn't a satisfactory solution)